# Striked out links behave differently in chat room and in transcript

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

Check out [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19889779#19889779) message.

If you enter the room, you'll see that it's linked and shows like this: <s>[test/link/with/strikeout/](http://test.com/link/with/strikeout/)</s>. In the transcript however, it reads like this: <s>http​://te​st/link/with/strikeout/</s>, without a link.

Comment: [That message](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19889779#19889779) is copyrighted by [the real poster](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3459110/awal-garg) of it, who happens to be [me](http://stackexchange.com/users/3333488/awal-garg)!